# magento template xml: add a static block to the product description of all products in specific category

Tags: xml, templates, magento

Using Magento 1.4.1.1 or 1.5.0.0 and given products that are associated with a specific category, I need to append a static block to the product description in single view.

I can create the static blocks (measurement images) and add simple append code in local.xml. However, I cannot figure out how to limit the application of the append to products of *certain categories only*.

EG: All shoe product single view pages (in shoe category, of course) should display a shoe size measurement image, skirts a skirt size measurement image, etc.

I don't really want to go so far as overriding the template... just want to append a block!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a custom block type (You can call it `Somemodule_Categorical_Cms_Block`, or pick a not-crappy name) that descends from `cms/block`. In that block class, implement something like this:

```
protected function _toHtml()
{
    if(!$this->isEnabledForCategory()) {
        return "";
    }
    return parent::_toHtml();
}
```

Implement your own `isEnabledForCategory` to check the category. Change your local.xml declaration to call your new block class, and you should be set to go.

Hope that helps!

Thanks,
Joe

Comment: This is not what I was thinking of, but it will accomplish all my purposes nicely. Thanks!

Comment: Although I am wondering why you think that the template alteration below is a better answer? I guess to me they are about equal except that yours allows me to keep everything in layout.xml and an additional block... which, as far as I can tell, is much more powerful in magento's idea of a modular templating system.

Comment: I tend to be leery of overriding blocks in general, though you could technically do it w/o overriding completely. It is perhaps a more nuanced issue depending on how much customization you'll do here in the future...

Comment: IMO magento... since they have a million miles of xml anyway... should already have a way to check for attributes, categories or any value affecting any entity when that entity is referenced in the xml config. Magento's xml config is similar in approach to TYPO3's typoscript... but unlike typoscript, or the DOM in javascript, magento's xml config seems to give almost no access to pertinent environmental variables. I mean, you can filter things six ways from Sunday... but once you get the collection, there is no way for the layout to know about those filters (AFAIK)... its messed up.

Answer (score 2):

If you can assume a product belongs to one category only then you can check in the template file like this:

```
$product = Mage::registry('current_product');
$category = $product->getCategory(); // get first category only
if ($category->getUrlKey() == 'shoes'):
    // Output show size measurements
elseif ($category->getUrlKey() == 'skirts'):
    // Output skirt measurements
endif;
```

Here I used `getUrlKey` since it provides text you typed in the admin so is manageable.

A more sophisticated way would be to use the "Custom Layout Update" field in each product's "Design" tab to put the XML in directly, but that is more work.

Comment: As I read the question, it's a CMS block so there is no template here. However, if you are correct that there is a template, this is a much better answer than overriding blocks.

Comment: You are correct, a CMS block was intended. However I read "static" as something that doesn't change, like a theme file, whereas I consider managed content to be dynamic, it depends on reading a database and can change when you're not expecting it. Then again, that's just my odd perception.

Comment: magento is... let's just say, in the mildest terms, I don't like magento very much. The templating system is so convoluted as to be unuseable. In any case, there is a way that you can do a javascript-like append in the templating system xml. Its actually a cool idea if it were well executed. My question was, "how do I tell the append to only occur to products of category [x]?" I presume that there is a way to do this, but the answer above is basically telling me, "you have to override the actual template file..." which will probably mean a more evil update scenario every 4 or so months.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to do such a thing and i came up with this:
1- create a static block named "category1_size_guide"
2- as long as my theme uses:
"\app\design\frontend\theme_designer\theme_name\template\page\2columns-right.phtml"
for display product, i add this code:

```
$product = Mage::registry('current_product');
$catIds = ($product)?$product->getCategoryIds():array(); //print_r($catIds);
if(in_array(60, $catIds)){ //60 is category id you want to check
    echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('category1_size_guide')->toHTML();
}
```